# YiiMongoDbSuite not working

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

Thanks for reading ,im using YiiMongoDbSuite extension to connect to mongo db
i downloaded mongo-php driver from   https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads added php_mongo.dll in /ext folder, modified php.ini file ,but still getting below error,

```
   include(Mongo.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Php Info:

```
System : Windows NT SKS10 5.2 build 3790 (Windows XP Professional x64 Edition   
Service Pack 1) i586
Build Date : Nov 20 2009 17:20:57
Compiler : MSVC6 (Visual C++ 6.0)
Architecture :x86 
PHP API :   20090626
PHP Extension : 20090626
Zend Extension : 220090626
Zend Extension Build : API220090626,TS,VC6
PHP Extension Build : API20090626,TS,VC6
```

code included in main.php

```
import'=>array(
     'ext.YiiMongoDbSuite.*',
),
    'mongodb' => array(
    'class'            => 'EMongoDB',
    'connectionString' => 'mongodb://sks10',//'mongodb://localhost',
    'dbName'           => 'users',
    'fsyncFlag'        => true,
    'safeFlag'         => true,
    'useCursor'        => false
  ),

  can anyone say wat im missing...
```

[image]

Now getting this error when i added new mongo-1.1.4-php5.3vc9.dll

Comment: Have you restarted apache? Have you checked your PHP info function for gthe ext? Have you added it to the right php.ini? Have you added the dll to the right ext folder?

Comment: Also it should be noted that later MongoDB versions do not support windows XP

Comment: yes i restarted apache,there is no mongo word present in php info function

Comment: im using compatible version only,created collections in mongodb also

Comment: im newbie to yii,parden if i used some wrong terminologies and asked silly questions...

Comment: It's ok there is no silly questions here, just very hard to debug this without seeing your computer, most of the time it is just saying a list of stuff until one works

Comment: Mongo.php where this file will be present??

Comment: It is one of the core files of the extension but it is a deprecated version of it: http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/class.mongo.php

Comment: using mongo-1.1.4-php5.3vc9 dll file...actully the service has been started in other system, im connecting to that and using it,

Comment: edited my post and added error image, now u getting close to it @Sammaye

Comment: The image you've added highlights the problem: you are trying to use a version of the MongoDB PHP driver compiled with VC9 with a PHP installation compiled with VC6 (the two have to match). The best solution is probably to update your version of PHP as this is very old and many bugs will have been fixed in both PHP and the MongoDB driver. If you can't upgrade PHP for some reason, it looks like the corresponding DLL that might work is `mongo-1.1.4-php5.3vc6` (from `mongo-1.1.4zip` at https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html). I would **strongly** encourage updating instead.